# Content-Security-Policy error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm working on a chrome extension and using content scripting to execute this code on the page

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
try{
$('input[type="submit"]').click();
}
catch(err){
($('input[type="button"]').attr('onclick'))(event);
}

});
```

and I get this error
"Refused to apply inline style because of Content-Security-Policy."
the manifest.json code:

```
{
  "name": "sites faxana ads clicking exception",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "name": "Make this page red"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: my question is how to solve this error and execute this code

Comment: This error shouldn't be causing anything to fail...other than styles.
You should probably change default-src to 'self' 'unsafe-inline' because it looks like you're getting that error with an inline style.

Comment: I didn't write any inline style code :/

Comment: Apparently jQuery is writing inline style code. The complete error message should give you a clearer idea whether you should change `default-src` or maybe even better, `style-src`.

Answer (score 5):

You're probably using an inline `<style>.selector { ... }</style>` in your head. Your CSP prevents you from doing this. Instead, use a `<link rel...>`.

For more info, see this nice article on the topic: https://mikewest.org/2011/10/secure-chrome-extensions-content-security-policy

Comment: No, it is because of the `onclick` thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you included jQuery.  Remove everything from your background.html page except for the jQuery include (I tried jQuery 1.7.1) and you get 5 errors in the console in Chrome 18.0.1003.1.

I've filed a bug with jQuery via their forums.